# How to convert the int value to inch in PHP

Tags: php

I just want to know how to convert inch based on the integer inputted in the field.

For Example:

```
$int = $_POST['int']; //value 1

//computation here...

$inch = //formula

//echoing the inch
echo $inch;
```

Comment: can you clarify your question?? convert to inch from what??

Comment: Is that interger value represents meter or centimeter or foot? you at least have to give us that to give you a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want convert from centimeter can you use this source

```
function cm2inches($cm)
{
     $inches = $cm/2.54;
     $inches = $inches%12;
     return sprintf('%d ins', $inches);
}
echo cm2inches(162);
```

You will have result

```
3 ins
```